# how to scroll to top in editor when user stop writing in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

i tried from scrolToAsync method but not working .on xaml when stop writing message or 
    keyboard keydown button is pressed control goes to start of message.when keyboard 
    keydown click,editor control goes to start of the message.
    i use this method on editor propertyChanged.

```
   double iScrollPosition = 0;
   await  editorScrollView.ScrollToAsync(0, iScrollPosition, true);
   <Frame Margin="10">
        <ScrollView x:Name="editorScrollView" >
           <Editor x:Name="txtEditor" 
                   HeightRequest="110" 
                   Placeholder="Write message here" 
                   PropertyChanged="OnStatusLabelPropertyChanged" />
        </ScrollView>
   </Frame>
```

can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **CustomRenderer** and implement it in specific platforms.

### in Android

```
using Android.Content;
using xxx.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using static Android.Widget.TextView;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor), typeof(MyEditorRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        public MyEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.FocusChange += Control_FocusChange;
            }
        }

        private void Control_FocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!e.HasFocus)
            {
                Control.SetSelection(0);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

### in iOS

```
using System;


using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using xxx.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Editor),typeof(MyEditorRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
     public class MyEditorRenderer:EditorRenderer,IUITextViewDelegate
     {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.Ended += Control_Ended;
            }

        }

        private void Control_Ended(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var editor = sender as UITextView;

            editor.ScrollRangeToVisible(new NSRange(0,0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry

Comment: You just need to add this two class in specific platform projects .